# Increasing property of solution of heat equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation

Let $$u_t - \Delta u = f$$
with $u(t,0) = u(t,1) = 0$ and $u(0,x) = u_0(x)$ given, and $f(t,x)$ is also given. This is the heat equation on the interval $(0,1)$.

How can I choose $f$ and $u_0$ to ensure that $u$ is increasing with respect to time? I.e. if $t \geq s$ then $u(t,x) \geq u(s,x)$ for a.e. $x$?

If $f \equiv 0$, then $u$ is decreasing with respect to $t$. But I don't know how to ensure that it becomes increasing. Does anyone know?

Comment: For example if $f=f(t)$ then $u$ is independent on $x$ and satisfies $u_t=f$, so it is increasing if $f\ge 0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro This only works if $u_0$ is constant.

Comment: @StopUsingFacebook It is not true that $u(\cdot,x)$ is decreasing if $f=0$. Solutions to the homogeneous heat equation with nonnegative initial data are strictly positive. This means that $u(\cdot,x)$ cannot be decreasing for $x$ outside the support of $u_0$.

Comment: @MaoWao: That is true.

Answer (score -1):

For the Allen-Cahn equation, $u_t = \epsilon^2 u_{xx} + u - u^3$, it's possible to have $u(t, x) \geq u(s, x), (t \geq s)$. The AC equation can be viewed as the $L^2$ gradient of the Ginzburg-Landau free energy $E = \int_\Omega 1/2 \epsilon^2 |u_x|^2 + 1/4(1 - u^2)^2 \mathrm{d} x$. The second term is called a double-well potential. If $u_0 = c \in (0, 1)$ in $[a, b]$, then the solution $u$ will evolve to $1$ finally.

Comment: You seem to be discussing a different PDE. How is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Well, the AC equaiton has the form $u_t -  \Delta u = f(u)$ with $f(u) = u - u^3, \epsilon = 1$, it belongs to the class of parabolic equations, or the heat equation called by the author.  The difference is that the $f(t, x)$ term in the heat equation does not depend on $u$.